# Are VS code extensions OS independent?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am a complete beginner in extensions development but I need to make one for work purposes. Before doing that I need my extension to be OS **independent**, do I need to take any steps for that?

Comment: for file paths use the `path` module and your good to go, and look at the methods of `vscode.Uri` and `vscode.workspace.fs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, yes, the vscode extensions should run on any platform that vscode runs on.  As rioV8 indicated, be aware of how some functions work on different platforms, mainly working with files/file systems.

Since vscode is cross platform compatible, the extensions it runs are also.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview#_cross-platform